# Why is my component's local state affected by changes in the global state?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components sitting side by side: Local and Global.
Local has a local state and Global has a global state.

1. I click Local: Local's state updates.
2. I click Global: Global's state updates and *Local's state reverts to its initial state*.

```
export default function MyApp() {

  const [global, setGlobal] = useState(0)

  function Local() {
    const [local, setLocal] = useState(0)
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setLocal(1)} >
        {local}
      </button>
    )
  }

  function Global() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setGlobal(1)}>
        {global}
      </button>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Local /> <Global />
    </>
  );
}
// Initial render:  0 0
// Click on Local:  1 0 
// Click on Global: 0 1
```

Why is this?

Comment: don't use a hook outside of a component.

Comment: `<Global />` should also not be inside of `<MyApp />`. Do not **ever** define a component inside of another component. Components like that do not only kill performance, they are plain broken. They unmount, get destroyed and a new one gets mounted on *every single render*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Local` component gets redeclared each time `MyApp` re-renders because it's defined within `MyApp`'s body. Move it outside of MyApp and this problem will go away.

```
function Local() {
  const [local, setLocal] = useState(0)
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setLocal(1)} >
      {local}
    </button>
  )
}


export default function MyApp() {

  const [global, setGlobal] = useState(0)

  function Global() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setGlobal(1)}>
        {global}
      </button>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Local /> <Global />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In react there's no such thing as global state.

```
  const [global, setGlobal] = useState(0)
```

The above line has two issues: a) it can't be defined outside the component function scope; b) as I mentioned every state is LOCAL. Remember that. If you are interested at global state, search "state management for React".